# ngOnDestroy not clearing value

Tags: angular

I am having an issue where the below service that I subscribe to is not being cleared when I leave the component

I am consoling out the `data` value below. The first time I get to the component the value of `data` is `{}`. Then I have code that populates `data` as i continue in the journey.

However if I leave the component I have an `ngOnDestroy` method which should clear the subscription but what I am seeing is that when I come back to the component `data` is still populated

Here is my code

*TS*

```
private subscriptions: Subscription[] = [];

this.subscriptions.push(this.accordianStateService.openState$.subscribe(data => {
  console.log(data)
}));

ngOnDestroy() {
  this.subscriptions.forEach((sub) => {
    sub.unsubscribe();
  });
}
```

*Service*

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { BehaviorSubject, Observable, Subject } from 'rxjs';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class SidePanelAccordianService {
private _openStateBehaviorSubject = new BehaviorSubject<{ id: string; state: boolean }>({} as { id: string; state: boolean });

  public openState$ = this._openStateBehaviorSubject.asObservable();

  public setOpenState(data: { id: string, state: boolean }) {
    this._openStateBehaviorSubject.next(data);
  }
}
```

Any idea why the data is not being unsubscribed to correctly?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's populated because you used [`BehaviorSubject`](https://www.learnrxjs.io/learn-rxjs/subjects/behaviorsubject), which sends last emitted value to every new subscriber.

Example (from the learnrxjs above):

```js
import { BehaviorSubject } from 'rxjs';

const subject = new BehaviorSubject(123);

// two new subscribers will get initial value => output: 123, 123
subject.subscribe(console.log);
subject.subscribe(console.log);

// two subscribers will get new value => output: 456, 456
subject.next(456);

// new subscriber will get latest value (456) => output: 456
subject.subscribe(console.log);

// all three subscribers will get new value => output: 789, 789, 789
subject.next(789);

// output: 123, 123, 456, 456, 456, 789, 789, 789
```

So, when you send new value, destroy the component and then create component once again, the new component will get the last set value, not the initial one.

Comment: Thanks, so I need to see how I can use `Subject` instead of `BehaviorSubject `

Comment: Yeah, `Subject` won't emit last value to the subscriber, so that would be one of the possible solutions. `Subject` and `BehaviorSubject` have the same API. Remember, `Subject` doesn't have initial value. You can learn more at [learnrxjs.io](https://www.learnrxjs.io/learn-rxjs/subjects/subject) which is great for learning rxjs. There is also [comparison between different subjects](https://www.learnrxjs.io/learn-rxjs/subjects) available